# Modifying a javascript file using a bash script

Tags: javascript, bash

During local development on Mac OSX 10, this Meteor project has a `ddp.js` file which contains lines like this:

```
//let abcConnection = DDP.connect('https://abc.com.au');  //push to cloud
let abcConnection = DDP.connect('http://localhost:3000');  //local dev.
```

Before I run a bash script to build and push the project to the cloud, I must change the lines to this:

```
let abcConnection = DDP.connect('https://abc.com.au');  //push to cloud
//let abcConnection = DDP.connect('http://localhost:3000');  //local dev.
```

i.e. comment and uncomment the relevant lines. How can I automate this since it needs to be done on multiple files in different projects? thx

Comment: why not define the endpoint in a package file and run a local or production package? https://guide.meteor.com/writing-atmosphere-packages.html#exporting https://guide.meteor.com/writing-atmosphere-packages.html#exporting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# before 
sed -ie 's$http://localhost:3000$https://abc.com.au$g' ddp.js

# Do deploy or build

# after
sed -ie 's$https://abc.com.au$http://localhost:3000$g' ddp.js
```